# Induction $\left(H_{n}\right)^{n}>\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k}{n-k}$

Tags: inequality, induction

I want to prove the following inequality :
$$\left(H_{n}\right)^{n}>\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k}{n-k}$$
Well for $n=0$ it's trivial that the inequality holds, let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ let's suppose the property is true for $n$, and let's show it for $n+1$.
Which means
$$\left(H_{n+1}\right)^{n+1}>\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k}{n+1-k}$$
I can't proceed because the hint says to use Bernouilli inequality :
$$(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx$$

Comment: @ThomasAhle actually,  that was an edit after my comment. Before, the numerator was $1.$ Now it is $k.$

Comment: An alternative proof might use: $$\begin{align} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k}{n-k}&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j}^{n-1}\frac1{n-k}\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}H_{n-j}\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}H_i
\end{align} $$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k}{n-k} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n-k}{k} = n(H_n-1).$$ According to Bernoulli's inequality you have
$$H_n^n = ((H_n-1)+1)^n \ge n(H_n-1) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k}{n-k}$$ for all $n$.

Comment: Bernoulli has a $1+$ on the right side, which is why you get the strict $>$ without the $1.$